# Jenkins + CMake for multiple OS and library versions

Tags: c++, jenkins, cmake

My C++ program is compiled for multiple OS (Win7, MacOS & Linux) using CMake.

For OS dependent stuff, I am doing things like:

```
if (${APPLE})
    // Do MacOS dependent things here
elseif(${WIN32})
    // Do Win dependent things here
elseif(${UNIX})
    // Do Linux dependent things here
endif (${APPLE})
```

Now, I need to link my program against different versions of a library. Continuing the same way will quickly become unpractical.

**How could I compile my program for multiple OS against multiple versions of a library while keeping everything practical so that it is easy to add new OS and/or new versions of the library?**

Eventually, everything will be integrated with Jenkins so I don't know if it is better to work at CMake or Jenkins level (or both).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's probably no "correct" answer here.  The purpose of CMake is to provide a Cross-Platform Make (hence the name) and as such, it provides many ways to reduce or eliminate platform-specific code.

I tend to find that the majority of cases where I need platform-specific blocks are either during dependency lookups ([`find_library`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3afind_library), [`find_file`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3afind_file), etc) or to set compiler/linker flags.  (Of course, my experience may not be typical or even applicable in your case).  This generally means that there aren't too many places in a given CMakeLists file where I need platform- or compiler-specific code.

One possible way to clean up would be to have all the platform-specific code in separate files and just [`include`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.10/cmake.html#command%3ainclude) each in a single `if` `elseif` `else` block.

Comment: thanks for your answer. For each library and each OS, you need different header/binaries paths. find_library and find_file would work for "standard" libraries only right?

Comment: Also, I need to work with several versions of the same library. Then, is it better to write one CMake for each version? Or pass the library version to CMake as an argument?

Comment: `find_library` and `find_file` would work for *any* library or file - not just standard ones.  You can help CMake find items in non-standard locations by adding search paths.  As to your question about the versions, I'd personally code the required minimum version into the CMake files.  It seems a bit odd that different platforms require different versions though.  It might be worth looking at bringing them all to the same version?

Comment: Thanks. No, this is perfectly understandable when you write plugins for different versions of the same software. Then, for each OS, you have to produce N versions, N being the number of software versions you want to support.